# Recommended books for learning iPhone with Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Are there any books that people on stackoverflow would recommend for development with the new Xcode? Prefer intermediate and beginner books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there are yet, but keep an eye out for the updated version of the Hillegass book to come out sometime this year (that's just a guess).

[http://www.amazon.com/iPhone-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides/dp/0321706242/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1301372927&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321706242)

I think this is the best iPhone programming book.  Honestly, the differences between XCode 3 & 4 are significant, but it's not too challenging to work through the differences.  It's mostly UI changes, so once you know the new place to go, you're golden.

Note, Hillegass has mentioned the 4th edition in the works: http://twitter.com/AaronHillegass/status/48493059322818560

I've not seen a release date yet.